# URLSearchParams is not a constructor in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am facing this error while using `URLSearchParams`

> TypeError: url__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.URLSearchParams is not a constructor

This is how I am calling:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search); // <- ERORR
    const ingredients = {};
    for (let param in query.entries()) {
        // ['salad', '1']
        ingredients[param[0]] = +param[1];
    }
    this.setState({ingredients : ingredients});
}
```

My ReactJS Project details:

```
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
"react-scripts": "3.0.1"
},
```

Comment: I think you don't need `URLSearchParams`, you can directly get params using `this.props.location.match.params`. check this - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/hitchhikers-guide-to-react-router-v4-4b12e369d10/

Comment: I *think* this is due to webpack not being configured to target browsers.

Comment: How to target browser? Where I can find this configuration?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This happens when react import UrlSearchParams from 'url'
So you have to remove this and try it. It will definitely work.

Comment: this is right, `import { URLSearchParams } from "url"` was causing this issue, after removing it solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should load `location` from `react-router-dom`. This will let you access the location and url params from the router. Please be careful to also pass your user Incase your app requires authentication to the component itself..

I am not sure what `search` does to tell you the truth, but location should be easily available to you through |react-router-dom`